# c# visual studio folder path

Tags: c#, path, directory

I have a problem while trying to access files stored int the solution explorer.

[image: Files in solution explorer]

I need to access file 1.wav, but the path res\notes\1.wav isn't working. Is there a function to get access to this directory?

This is how its currently working:

```
String path = @"C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\res\notes\" + mk.note + ".wav";
```

Now I want to have the files stored within the application, ie if I package and export my app the files go with it.

Comment: Run time, Compile time or design time?

Comment: i need this to be accessed all times, so if I move the project's path I won't have to change the file's location

Comment: How you are accessing it currently? Any code?

Comment: You have to share what you've tried so far... otherwise there's not much we could do about it

Comment: And who (i mean file/class/object) in your solution wants to have access to those files...

Comment: This is how its currently working: String path = @"C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\res\notes\" + mk.note + ".wav"; now I want to have the files stored within the application, ie if I package and export my app the files go with it

Comment: you could make them embedded resources or make an installer.

Comment: Also, is it marked as Content, Embedded Resource, or None ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your string from

```
 String path = @"C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\res\notes\" + mk.note + ".wav";
```

to

```
String path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "res\notes\" + mk.note + ".wav");
```

Maybe you have to add the folders and copy the files manual when copy your program to another location.